# 400 Bad request - REST JSON c#

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I've created a C# WCF project, when I'm testing it using POSTMAN or Fiddler. I've received an error: "400 Bad Request". Also I've created an C# windows project to test, it is the same result as well. Here's my WCF Project.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "api/createpr.json")]
    PRApplication AddPR(RequestData rData);

}
```

I'm using this code when testing.

```
            try
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/WEB_Service_B1/Service1.svc/api/createpr.json");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{\"Test\"}";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
```

Is there any problem also in my Web.config?

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <authentication mode="Windows" />
      <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WS_B1.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="WS_B1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WS_B1.Service1Behavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WS_B1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You are using localhost without port? It is not supposed to look like this- http://localhost:58108/WEB_Service_B1/Service1.svc/api/createpr.json.   with your relevant port?

Comment: Yes, http://localhost/WEB_Service_B1. It uses port 80 and the alias for that is WEB_Service_B1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped
```

This means the request needs to be a full json object. Try with the following request body:

```
string json = "{\"rData\": {\"PropertyName\": \"Test\"}}";
```

Where `PropertyName` is a public property of `RequestData` class of string type.

Comment: Really appreciated it. But as I test it: **The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**